# Is it possible to forward whole chat/group posts using telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) library to write a bot in Python that forwards all group posts to another group where the bot is administrator.

Is there any method that I could use to access all posts of a group/chat?

something like this?

```
async def forward_messages(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    chat = await context.bot.get_chat("<group-id>")
    #get_messages??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. The methods available for bots are listed in Telegrams [Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).